# How to concatenate two dimensional ranges, while ignoring blanks from both ranges?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have this google sheets [file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J8vQqUHWYPKozazGmlVRJplgaapS2qaXyULU5jHAc7M/copy) with input tabels: `Input Range 01` and `Input Range 02`

 How to get the output table using the simplest formula and the fewest range references possible? and if lambda and lhf can be avoided is better. see [this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHifx.png)

Input Range 01

| E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Set 1 | Set 2 | Set 3 |
| Set 1 | Set 2 | Set 3 |
| Set 1 | Set 2 | Set 3 |
| Set 1 | Set 2 |  |
| Set 1 | Set 2 | Set 3 |
|  | Set 2 | Set 3 |

Input Range 02

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Category 1 | Category 1 | Category 1 |
|  | Category 2 | Category 2 |
| Category 3 | Category 3 |  |
| Category 4 | Category 4 | Category 4 |
|  |  |  |
| Category 6 | Category 6 | Category 6 |

Output

| I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Set 1 Category 1 | Set 2 Category 1 | Set 3 Category 1 |
|  | Set 2 Category 2 | Set 3 Category 2 |
| Set 1 Category 3 | Set 2 Category 3 |  |
| Set 1 Category 4 | Set 2 Category 4 |  |
|  | Set 2 Category 6 | Set 3 Category 6 |

[image]

Here what i tryed

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A2:C7&" "&E2:G7)
```

and tried to clean it with merging true and false ranges for empty cells in both ranges. With the previous formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LAMBDA(f, FILTER(f,f<>"" )(IF((A2:C>1*(A2:C<>""))*(E2:G>1*(E2:G<>""))=1,A2:C&" "&E2:G,""))))
```

At that point i was circling in loops to get it to work and...this error. If possible, avoid using Lambda due to its limitations. I know i created alot of references. I was planning to replace them with Lambda names, but it is out of consideration only if bypassed limitations with ignoring blanks `IF(Range="",,[The rest of the formula])`.

[image]

Comment: not mine downvote but I do wonder whats the issue with this question... no judging but level of difficulty here is almost absent and I am pretty sure your gs level is much higher these days

Comment: @player0 I think these questions provide a short series of basic "how to"s. Personally, I think  this is how all questions should be. If they're not, they need to be focussed at this level. All the rest should be downvoted and closed.

Comment: I need to use it in another project and i can't create a solution with the least refrences. in terms of domnvots im talking to reviewers without google sheet high reputation they always drive by *** @player0 thank to your answers im getting better.

Comment: I did this `=ARRAYFORMULA(A2:C7&" "&E2:G7)` with more formulas to clean it, did't want to include it to get a new approaches.

Comment: @Osm Only if you include it, you'll get other approaches. Otherwise, we'll be just repeating the same.

Comment: @player0 Highly doubtful that you'll get this through Google search. Suggest me a search term and let's see if something comes up.

Comment: @player0 Even if it did, I think OP is specifically asking for alternative approaches: to quote `simplest formula and the fewest range references possible?`

Comment: @TheMaster yes `simplest, fewest range`

Comment: Is there a relationship between the ranges? Will it always be to the left?

Comment: Please do [edit] to include the formula you used and all the formula used to clean up

Comment: The range doesnt chage i added blank `D` column for formatting

Comment: I'm asking if the category range will always be to the left of set range? If so, we can use `offset` to reduce 1 range reference.

Comment: @TheMaster Yes it is on the left, the edit will lead us to the lambda limitations again. I'll add it anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LAMBDA(rg,QUERY(IF((rg<>"")*(OFFSET(rg,0,4)<>""),OFFSET(rg,0,4)&" "&rg,),"where "&JOIN(" or ","Col"&SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(rg))&" is not null "),0))(A2:C7))
```

has the fewest range references using `LAMBDA`. `&` is used for dynamic concatenation. Uses `OFFSET` to reference the other range and `QUERY`'s `where Col is not null` to check if category is empty.

---

`MAP` is another alternative.`MAP` provides one value from each of the provided ranges:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LAMBDA(rg,QUERY(MAP(rg,OFFSET(rg,0,4),LAMBDA(cat,set,IF(cat="",,IF(set="",,set&" "&cat)))),"where "&JOIN(" or ","Col"&SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(rg))&" is not null"),0))(A2:C7))
```

Comment: Already did `=ARRAYFORMULA(A2:C7&" "&E2:G7)`

Comment: Doesn't handle the empty rows

Comment: And this is [MAP](https://i.imgur.com/0DlWfBQ.png)

Comment: I did See [this](https://i.imgur.com/jPHhHfH.png)

Comment: @Osm Last edit should've fixed it all.

Comment: Even with opend refrences and 5511 Rows  
 `=QUERY(MAP(A2:C,E2:G,LAMBDA(cat,set,IF(cat="",,IF(set="",,cat&" "&set)))),"where Col1 is not null or Col2 is not null or Col3 is not null",0)` Works perfctly, Thanks. i got dizzy this last hour.

Comment: Edit the Set and Category is reversed @themaster and this fix it `=QUERY(MAP(A2:C,E2:G,LAMBDA(cat,set,IF(cat="",,IF(set="",,set&" "&cat)))),"where Col1 is not null or Col2 is not null or Col3 is not null",0)` paste it in the answer.

Comment: @Osm Check update. Added a extra lambda, but should be much easier.